# Is this code safe?

Tags: c++

```
const std::string makeUniqueName()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    std::string s;                                                                                                             
    std::generate_n(const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()), 10, RndGenerator()); 
    return s;
}
```

Is this code safe: compiler does not report any warning message.

Comment: No, of course not. `generate_n` needs a place to write the data to.

Comment: If you find yourself using `const_cast` but you don't understand why, then the answer is almost certainly "No!"

Comment: Don't use `.c_str()` for writeable memory, use iterators. And **never return by const value**.

Comment: Btw returning by `const` value isn't unsafe, but it may cause inefficiencies for callers.

Comment: @SteveJessop, I did not say that it is unsafe; I just said that he should never do that. I included more reasoning for it in my answer.

Comment: Don't call `srand` each time - you'll get the same name if you call this twice within a second. Do it just once, when the program starts.

Comment: @Mike Calling srand once only doesn't really help. Will still get dupes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code obviously invokes undefined behavior by writing to yet unallocated memory. Either construct the string with enough space for those characters (`std::string s(10, 0);`) and pass `std::begin(s)` to `generate_n` or use  [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Furthermore, by using `const_cast` on a `const` pointer, you invoked undefined behavior again (removing `const` from a `const` object and then writing to it is undefined behavior).

Also: don't return by `const` values, it inhibits move semantics and you do *not* want that.

Comment: What would a full implementation of this function look like using the suggestions you have?

Comment: @MagnusHoff, well, I think OP should cope with the task of substituting parts of his own code with code resulting from my suggestions - reading an example on `back_inserter` or calling `std::begin()` isn't rocket science.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you will need to allocate some storage for the string if you want to write to it.

Perhaps more importantly, you must stop using `const_cast` on `c_str()`. You are not allowed to modify the memory that `c_str()` points to. As it stands, your code invokes undefined behaviour.

Even then your code will not necessarily generate a unique name each time it is called. You might call it twice very close together and `time(NULL)` returns the same thing for both calls. Or you might find that even with different seeds, your RNG returns the same value.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not safe!

Your string doesn't have anything in it, and you're trying to add 10 items to it. You need to reserve space in the string like this:

```
std::string s(10,' ');
```

If you're going to start writing directly to it.

Comment: Even if memory in the string was pre-allocated, it's really bad practice to try and write to a string using the c_str() pointer!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely not safe. The C++ standard explicitly forbids modification of values pointed to by c_str. The compiler does not complain because of const_cast, but still it is wrong.